# How do you change the colors on a WPF progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I have a WPF, vista style progressbar that I want to change the brushes on. I've set the foreground brush to another color, but there is a sort of whoosh animation effect whose color is still the default green. How can I change this?

Answer (score 11):

To do this you need to edit the ControlTemplate Styles for the Progress Bar control in your project.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}"
     TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Grid MinHeight="14" MinWidth="200">
          <Border 
            Name="PART_Track" 
            CornerRadius="2" 
            Background="{StaticResource PressedBrush}"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="1" />
          <Border 
            Name="PART_Indicator" 
            CornerRadius="2" 
            Background="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" 
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Example using these styles:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
  <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    <GradientStopCollection>
      <GradientStop Color="#BBB" Offset="0.0"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.1"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.9"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="1.0"/>
    </GradientStopCollection>
  </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>


...


<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" />


...


<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
  <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    <GradientStopCollection>
      <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#AAA" Offset="1.0"/>
    </GradientStopCollection>
  </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>


...


<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
  <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    <GradientStopCollection>
      <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
    </GradientStopCollection>
  </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

You can see an example of this on MSDN: [ProgressBar ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750638.aspx)